# Creating randomly generated objects in a 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

all. I'm working on a small game in which a 2D array is created to house each tile of the "map" of the game. The game spawns a player and a bunch of assorted items. The cells look like this:

```
private String [][] cells;

...

public void set(int cellX, int cellY, String str)
{
    cells[cellX][cellY] = str;
}
```

with each String stating what the cell in each place looks like. For instance, sometimes a wall spawns and sometimes passages are created (this is all read in from a file). So the question is this:

How can I randomly generate objects on certain cells? For instance, if I have 36 cells total (6x6), but only 23 of them can be "moved" on by the player, how can I randomly generate items that have an equal chance to spawn on each?

The code I have thus far is this.

```
public void draw()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < cells.length; x++)  
    {   
        for (int y = 0; y < cells[w].length; y++)   
        {   
            if(cells[x][y] == "W"){
                Cell wall = new Cell(config.wallImage());
                wall.draw(config, x, y);
            if(cells[x][y] == "P"){
                Cell passage = new CellPassage(config.passageImage());

                // This is where I need to check to see if the item is okay   
                // to be placed. If it is unable, nothing will be added to 
                // the Cell passage.
                //passage.attemptToAdd(item);

                passage.draw(config, x, y);
            }
        }   
    }    
    hero.draw();
}
```

Comment: I've read through your description twice, and I'm still not sure what you're trying to do, but as a side recommendation, I can say for sure don't do this: `if(cells[x][y] == "W"){`. don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=` since this compares for **object equality**, whether two objects are **identical** and that's not what you want. You want **functional equality**, and so use the `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` methods. So instead, do `if (cells[x][y].equals("W")) {`

Comment: Do you want to generate a maze? Should every "passage" be reachable from any other "passage"?

Comment: I agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels. Also, you're missing a closing `}` before the second `if`. And don't you mean `cells[x].length` in the second `if` too?

Comment: @n0rd essentially, yes. And in some of the maze area, objects spawn. For instance, if I needed 12 keys in the maze, they would spawn at random locations in the maze. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you, I changed this. I'm relatively new to java, so thank you for the explanation of that.

I am attempting to draw a maze, and in some spots of the maze, I need "objects" such as keys or gems to spawn.

Comment: Then problem is quite different from randomly dropping stuff into 2D array.

Comment: @DarronMartinez Sorry, but I still don't exactly know what you want. You want to insert an amount of random things on your map....ok. Is that your problem? Or is it verifying if things can be placed on some cell, because of some kind of restriction? Or is it something else? I'm confused.

Comment: @HugoSousa I am creating a grid of Cells, (6x6, for example), and each individual cell is either a Wall or a Passage. In the passages, there also needs to be items that spawn in random passage locations when the program is first run. Does this help?

Comment: @DarronMartinez ok, I get it. But what is the problem now? We only see your `draw` function. How are you defining that a passage has an item, since you're representing them with `String`? Have you sucessfully generated the place where that item will spawn or not? I think you need to provide us more information and give us the detailed problem you're facing.

Comment: @HugoSousa I have a `class` for the items themselves. It includes the object "Key" and "Gem". This class holds all the information for the Items.

Comment: @DarronMartinez But in your maze, you're representing them as `String`. Shouldn't you change your representation then?

Comment: The `String` is only used to represent the tile that is within the Cell. For instance, if, in the text file, the layout looks like:

**WPPPW
WPWPW
WPWPW
WPPPW**

Then the maze looks like a square.

Comment: @DarronMartinez Let me see if I understand. Wherever you've got a "P" (passage) in your maze, you want to generate, with some probability, a gem or key on this cell. Is that right? Is there a limit number of keys/gems to be spawn each time? What should that probability be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69700/discussion-between-darron-martinez-and-hugo-sousa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, had a discussion in chat with OP and this is the problem, which seemed a little confusing from the question post:

1. There are `Item`, such as `Key` and `Gem`, that may spawn in each round.
2. Those `Item` have a limit number that must be spawned every round. For example, there may spawn 5 `Gem` every round.
3. They must spawn in passages with an equal probability.

So, to solve this issue, my suggestion is:

1. Creating an `ArrayList` of `Cell`. Store all the cells of passages.
2. Generate a random number between 0 and array length - 1.
3. Repeat until the limit of needed items is reached.

It should look something like this:

```
public void addItem(Item item, int limit) 
{ 
    ArrayList<Cell> passages = new ArrayList<Cell>();

    for(int x = 0;  x < cells.length; x++) 
    { 
        for (int y = 0; y < cells[w].length; y++) 
        { 
            if (cells[x][y] == "P") //if it's a passage
                passages.add(new Cell(x,y)); 
        } 
    } 


    Random rand = new Random();
    while(spawnedItems < limit){

        if(passages.size() == 0)
            throw LimitImpossibleError();

        int randomNum = rand.nextInt(passages.size());

        items.add(new ItemPosition(item, passages.get(randomNum))); //assuming that you have a global ArrayList of Item and respective Cell (ItemPosition) to draw them later 
    }
}
```

Another question of the OP in the discussion was how to draw the `Item` later. So, I gave him 2 suggestions:

1. Change the representation of the maze to some Object that represents what's in the maze. For example, `CellInfo`, which could be parent of `Wall`, `Passage`, `Item`, etc. This, however, would require much change on the actual work. He's actually reading the maze from a file, for example.
2. Having an `ArrayList` with `Item` and the respective `Cell` where it should be drawn. In the `draw` method, after drawing all the walls and passages (the only things represented in the maze with `String`), traverse this `ArrayList` and draw them in the respective position.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an ArrayList of Points that are eligible to have an item on them, and then randomly select them using `[your ArrayList's name].get(Math.random() * [your ArrayList's name].size())`